# How to strip (CID:) when using camelot to extract text from pdfs

Tags: python-3.x, pdfminer, python-camelot

I'm using Camelot to extract text from pdfs.
The pdfs also contains Chinese characters for which Camelot prints **Cid** of the same. eg **(cid:3634)**

I want to strip off those CID as Chinese characters are not imp to me.

I tried this:

```
>>> tables = camelot.read_pdf('D:/iolo/1.  Hangcha/1.  FORKLIFTS ELECTRIC/2.  NK15E - 3 WHEEL - NEW-(2014)/copy.pdf',pages='12',strip_text='(cid:[0-9])')
```

But only removes the CID frame and not numbers in it.

[See example Output Image Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hwlCJ.png)
Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment, Camelot parameter `strip_text` doesn't support regular expressions (see [official repository](https://github.com/camelot-dev/camelot/blob/4edca28c53a4a41476b9083baafad646ba670d17/camelot/utils.py#L413)).

Instead, you can use Pandas `replace` method:

```
for table in tables:
    table.df.replace(to_replace='\(cid\:[0-9]+\)', value='', inplace=True, regex=True)
```